# Reading srt (subtitle) files with Python3

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-3.x

I wish to be able to read an srt file with python3.

These files can be found here: 
  http://www.opensubtitles.org/

With info here:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip

Subrip supports any encoding: ascii or unicode, for example.

If I understand correctly then I need to specify which decoder to use when I use pythons read function. So am I right in saying that I need to know how the file is encoded in order to make this judgement? If so how do I establish that for each file if I have a hundred such files with different sources and language support?

Ultimately I would prefer if I could convert the files so that they are all in utf-8 encoding to start with. But some of these files might be some obscure encoding for all I know.

Please help,

Barry

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`charade` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/charade) (formerly [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)) to detect the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of each `.srt` file to test for encoding.  However, this probably won't work for all files, as it is not a required attribute, and only specified in `UTF` files anyways.  A check can be performed by

```
testStr = b'\xff\xfeOtherdata'

if testStr[0:2] == b'\xff\xfe':
    print('UTF-16 Little Endian')
elif testStr[0:2] == b'\xfe\xff':
    print('UTF-16 Big Endian')
#...
```

What you probably want to do is simply open your file, then decode whatever you pull out of the file into unicode, deal with the unicode representation until you are ready to print, and then encode it back again.  See [this talk](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) for some more information, and code samples that might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks brc! How does one establish if the bom is present for a given file using python and how does one print the data associated with this bom?

Answer (score 1):

There's also a decent library for handling SRT files:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysrt

You can specify the encoding when opening and writing SRT files.